# How to access run time env variables in webpack config file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to run a create react app inside a docker container with Webpack 5 and ModuleFederation plugin configured. I wanted to build the app once and deploy in multiple environments with each environment loading its corresponding remotes. So I pass in the env variables during docker run like below

For illustration
`docker run -d -p 3000:8080 -e REACT_APP_DEPLOY_ENV=dev my-app`

My webpack config (react-app-rewired)

```
    webpack(config, env) {
        if (env === 'development') {
            config.plugins.push(
                new ModuleFederationPlugin({
                    name: 'my-app',
                    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
                    remotes: {
                        remoteApp: "remoteApp@http://localhost:8888/remoteEntry.js"
                    },
                    exposes: {
                    },
                    shared: {
                        ...deps,
                        react: {
                            singleton: true,
                            requiredVersion: deps.react,
                        },
                        'react-dom': {
                            singleton: true,
                            requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
                        },
                    },
                })
            );
        } else {
            const env = process.env.REACT_APP_DEPLOY_ENV
            config.plugins.push(
                new ModuleFederationPlugin({
                    name: 'my-app',
                    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
                    remotes: {
                        remoteApp: `remoteApp@https://myapp-${env}.com/remoteEntry.js`
                    },
                    exposes: {
                    },
                    shared: {
                        ...deps,
                        react: {
                            singleton: true,
                            requiredVersion: deps.react,
                        },
                        'react-dom': {
                            singleton: true,
                            requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
                        },
                    },
                })
            );
            config.plugins.push(
                new DefinePlugin({
                    'process.env.REACT_APP_DEPLOY_ENV': JSON.stringify(
                        process.env.REACT_APP_DEPLOY_ENV || 'dev'
                    ),
                })
            );
        }
        return config;
    },
};
```

But I am not able to access REACT_APP_DEPLOY_ENV in my webpack config. the env is `undefined`. When I exec into my container and do a printenv I see `REACT_APP_DEPLOY_ENV=dev`. How do I access this variable in my moduleFederation plugin to load my remote URL dynamically. Can someone help me here?

Comment: if you are trying to pass as a configuration parameter from docker to node, then try adding npm_config_ prefix. ex. `npm_config_react_app_deploy_env=dev`

Comment: @RahulKumar How does react app running behind nginx know the variable passed to node?

Comment: This is not possible at runtime. The solution is for build time only.

Answer (score 0):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env' : process.env
})
```

it will probably solve your problem